# Remove repeated Characters from a Text input

Tags: javascript

[This has been solved now]I want to run a little experiment with js but I just can't find out how to check in realtime if a character has been used before. If it has been yoused before there it should just delete them from the text field.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<body style="margin:10px;">
    <input id="text">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Step 1 is to try something.

Comment: What do you mean by `remove` ? You want to prevent the user from typing a character that is already present in the input ? Your question is unclear and you haven't tried anything. See [Javascript Event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/EventListener)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome
try like this

html

```
<body style="margin:10px;">
<div>
    <input id="text" type="text">
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('change', function() {
  this.value = removeRepeatedCharacters(this.value);
});
function removeRepeatedCharacters(string) {
  return string
    .split('')
    .filter(function(item, pos, self) {
      return self.indexOf(item) == pos;
    })
    .join('');
}
```

Comment: Ok that looks good... But I would have to submit it first right? Is there a way to do it in realtime?

Comment: no you don't need to submit it if you will change text in text area it change remove repeated characters. you can use another event `document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('keypress', function() {`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so as it turns out my friend has just done something himself and he said it's working. Thank you for your help anyways!!